# cd command in python

Tags: python, git

I am new to python and

I am trying to test syntaxnet in python using this [github repo](https://github.com/spoddutur/syntaxnet).

and in the section "how to run the parser" is as following :

> 1. git clone https://github.com/spoddutur/syntaxnet.git
> 2. cd <syntaxnet-git-clone-directory>
> 3. python main.py
> 4. That's it!!  It prints syntaxnet dependency parser output for given input english sentence

through some research, I understood that first one indicates that I need to install the syntaxnet package in my cmd so I did and the package was successfully installed.
but I don't understand how to perform the second one
what does cd do, and where and how should I use it?

also in main.py,

```
from my_parser_eval import SyntaxNetProcess
from my_parser_eval import _write_input
from my_parser_eval import _read_output
from my_parser_eval import pretty_print
```

eclipse cannot find those imports, even after I created a package/module named `my_parser_eval` that includes all necessary codes from the reference

Comment: it should read `cd syntaxnet`. And it's not a programming question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `cd` itself just changes into the `$HOME` dir of the current user. `pwd` prints the current dir ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Be aware the cd isn't blank, there is code after it, that isn's SO markdown friendly.

Comment: If you look at the instructions in the repo again, the correct step is:  `cd <syntaxnet-git-clone-directory>`. `cd <path>` is useful for navigating between directories using the terminal/command prompt. You should look at some cmd basics before you dig deeper into Python.

Comment: aaaah yes it's on windows. My bad.

Comment: In general, if an instruction tells you to do something "in my cmd", assume that all the next steps are also "in my cmd" unless there's an obvious reason why that wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **CD** command means **Change Directory**.

Once you have finished cloning Syntaxnet Github Repository, you should enter its directory. That's why you have to enter **CD** command.

But have in mind that CD takes one parameter - the directory you want to enter.

In order to solve your problem you must write `cd syntaxnet` resulting in:

```
git clone https://github.com/spoddutur/syntaxnet.git
cd syntaxnet
python main.py
```

**First command:**

[image: First commmand]

**Second command**

[image: Second command]

Comment: thank you. I thought I had to use it in IDE like eclipse so I have been trying to use it in Pydev of eclipse. so I just managed to run it but original main.py has syntax errors, I have been trying to solve errors but I just keep getting different erros as I revise the code. can you shortly take a look and explain why it does not work? I at least tried adding parenthesis to the codes that lack it and still does not work with the error " inconsistent use of tabs and spaces"